on second visit chart and button not working
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])) {
    if (!header("Location: index.php")) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        die("Unauthorized access");
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

require_once "DBClasses/restaurants.php";
require_once "DBClasses/billsettlement.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" />
    <title>GalaxyNx Reports</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i|Source+Sans+Pro:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="_manifest.json" data-pwa-version="set_in_manifest_and_pwa_js">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="app/icons/icon-192x192.png">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/charts/charts.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body class="theme-light" data-highlight="highlight-red" data-gradient="body-default">
    <div id="preloader"><div class="spinner-border color-highlight" role="status"></div></div>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="footer-bar" class="footer-bar-1">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Home</span></a>
            <a href="#" data-menu="menu-settings">
                <i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Settings</span></a>
            <a href="logout.php" data-menu="menu-settings">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i><span>Logout</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="content notch-clear">
                <div class="d-flex py-0">
                    <div class="align-self-center me-auto">
                        <strong class="text-uppercase opacity-60 font-11">Welcome Back</strong>                                                                 
                        <p class="color-facebook text-start font-12">Todays is <?php echo date(
          "d-M-Y"
      ); ?>
                    </div>
                                                                                    
                    <div class="align-self-center ms-auto">
                        <a href="#" class="d-block icon icon-l bg-blue-dark rounded-xl mb-1" data-menu="menu-sidebar-left-1">
                            <i class="fa fa-solid fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
   $allrestaurants = getallresturants();
   if ($allrestaurants) {
       $i = 0;
       $tdate = date("Y-m-d");
       foreach ($allrestaurants as $restaurant) {
           $alls = getSettlementSummary($restaurant["restaurantid"], $tdate);
           if ($alls) {
               $json_data = json_decode($alls["billsettlement"], true);

               if ($json_data !== null) {

                   $totalonline =
                       $json_data["PaytmAmount"] +
                       $json_data["GPayAmount"] +
                       $json_data["APayAmount"] +
                       $json_data["BhimAmount"] +
                       $json_data["DOtherAmount"];
                   $gdata =
                       $json_data["CashAmount"] .
                       "," .
                       $totalonline .
                       "," .
                       $json_data["CcAmount"] .
                       "," .
                       $json_data["MealPassAmount"] .
                       "," .
                       $json_data["CreditAmount"] .
                       "," .
                       $json_data["MemberAmount"] .
                       "," .
                       $json_data["RoomAmount"] .
                       "," .
                       $json_data["OnlineDebit"];
                   ?>
            <div class="content mb-0">
                
                <h4 class="text-center font-700 text-uppercase font-16 opacity-100 mb-0 color-google " ><?php echo $restaurant[
        "restaurantname"
    ]; ?></h4>              
                <p class="color-black text-center mb-2 mt-0 ">
                    <?php
     $lstsync = getLastSyncTime();

     if ($lstsync) {
         $_SESSION["syncdatetime"] = $lstsync[0]["syncdatetime"];
         $dateTime = new DateTime($lstsync[0]["syncdatetime"]);
         $twelveHourFormat = $dateTime->format("d-M-Y h:i A");
         echo "Last Sync. at : " . $twelveHourFormat;
     } else {
         $_SESSION["syncdatetime"] = "";
         echo "Last Sync. at : ";
     }
     ?>
                </p>        
                <div class="card card-style">
                    <div class="content mb-0">
                        <div class="row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-6 pe-0">
                                <div class="chart-container mb-2" style="width:100%; height:350px;">
                                    <?php echo '<canvas class="graph" id="doughnut-chart"/>'; ?>
                                </div>
                                <script>
                                    (async function()
                                    {                                   
                                        var redFull = '#BF263C';
                                        var redFade = 'rgba(191, 38, 60, 0.2)';
                                        var yellowFull = '#F6BB42';
                                        var yellowFade = 'rgba(246, 187, 66, 0.2)';
                                        var greenFull = '#8CC152';
                                        var greenFade = 'rgba(140, 193, 82, 0.1)';
                                        var greenFade2 = 'rgba(140, 193, 82, 0.7)';
                                        var blueFull = '#5D9CEC';
                                        var blueFade = 'rgba(93, 156, 236, 0.2)';
                                        var blueFade2 = 'rgba(93, 156, 236, 0.7)';
                                        var magentaFull = '#AC92EC';
                                        var magentaFade = 'rgba(172, 146, 236, 0.2)';
                                        var grayFull = '#CCD1D9';
                                        var grayFade = 'rgba(204, 209, 217, 0.2)';
                                        var orangeFull = '#E9573F';
                                        var orangeFade = 'rgba(233, 87, 63, 0.2)'
                                        var facebookColor = 'rgba(66,103,178, 0.8)';
                                        var twitterColor = 'rgba(29,161,242, 0.8)';
                                        var whatsappColor = 'rgba(37,211,102,0.8)';


                                        //var doughnutChart = document.querySelectorAll('#doughnut-chart')[0]
                                        <?php echo "var doughnutChart = document.querySelectorAll('#doughnut-chart')[" .
              $i .
              "]"; ?>


                                        var doughnutDemoChart = new Chart(doughnutChart, {
                                            type: 'doughnut',
                                            data: {
                                                labels: ["Cash", "Online", "Credit Card", "Meal Pass", "Credit", "Membership", "Room Guest", "Online Debit"],
                                                datasets: [{
                                                    backgroundColor: [magentaFull, blueFull, whatsappColor,greenFull,twitterColor,grayFull,yellowFull,redFull],
                                                        borderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)",
                                                        <?php echo "data:[" . $gdata . "]"; ?>
                                                    }]
                                            },
                                            options: {
                                                responsive: true,
                                                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                                                plugins: {
                                                    legend: {
                                                        display: true,
                                                        position: 'bottom',
                                                        labels: {
                                                            fontSize: 13,
                                                            padding: 15,
                                                            boxWidth: 12
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                },
                                                tooltips: {
                                                    enabled: true
                                                },
                                                animation: {
                                                    duration: 1500
                                                },
                                                layout: {
                                                    padding: {
                                                        bottom: 30
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    })();
                                </script>

                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-6 ps-0">
                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                    <div class="col-6 pe-0">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-800 color-theme text-start">Total Sales</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 ps-0">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-800 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $json_data["NetAmount"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-1 mt-1"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-800 color-theme text-start">Total Bills</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-800 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $json_data["TotalBills"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-1 mt-1"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-800 color-theme text-start">Discount</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-800 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $json_data["Discount"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-1 mt-1"></div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-1 mt-1"></div>
                                    
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-start">Cash</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $json_data["CashAmount"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-0 mt-0"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-start">Online</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $totalonline,
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-0 mt-0"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-start">Credit Card</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $json_data["CcAmount"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-0 mt-0"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-start">Meal Pass</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $json_data["MealPassAmount"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-0 mt-0"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-start">Credit</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format($json_data["CreditAmount"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-0 mt-0"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-start">Membership</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $json_data["MemberAmount"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-0 mt-0"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-start">Room Guest</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $json_data["RoomAmount"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-0 mt-0"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-start">Online Debit</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                            <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo number_format(
               $json_data["OnlineDebit"],
               2
           ); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divider w-100 mb-0 mt-0"></div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-start"></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <!--<p class="font-12 mb-0 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                        <?php echo '<a href="#" onclick="postToHome(' .
              $restaurant["restaurantid"] .
              ')" class="btn btn-m mb-3 rounded-s  text-uppercase font-25 font-900  shadow-s border-red-dark  bg-red-light text-end">'; ?>
                                        Enter <span class="badge bg-transparent color-white mt-1 scale-icon ms-4 me-n2 float-end"><i class="fa fa-cog font-15 text-center"></i></span></a>
                                        </p>-->
                                        <!--<div class="list-group list-custom-large short-border"> -->
                                        <p class="font-12 mb-2 mt-2 font-500 color-theme text-end">
                                            <a href="#" class="icon rounded-xs me-1 icon-xs bg-fade-red-light" onclick="postToHome(<?php echo $restaurant[
               "restaurantid"
           ]; ?>,'<?php echo $restaurant["restaurantname"]; ?>')">
                                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right color-red-dark rounded-s"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                        <!--</div>-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
               }
               $i++;
           } else {
                ?>
            <div class="content mb-0">
                <h4 class="text-center font-700 text-uppercase font-16 opacity-100 mb-3 mt-n2 color-google " ><?php echo $restaurant[
        "restaurantname"
    ]; ?></h4>
                <div class="card card-style">
                    <div class="content mb-0">
                        <div class="row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-12 pe-0">
                                <p class="font-14 mb-0 font-800 color-theme text-center">No Data Found !!!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
           }
       }
   } else {
       echo "No Restaurant Registered !!!";
   }
   ?>

<script>
    function postToHome(branchid, branchname)
    {
        var params = {
            branchid1: branchid,
            branchname2: branchname
        };

        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.method = 'post';
        form.action = 'home.php';

        for (var key in params)
        {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(key))
            {
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'hidden';
                input.name = key;
                input.value = params[key];
                form.appendChild(input);
            }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
</script>

        </div>
        <!-- End of Page Content-->

        <div id="menu-sidebar-left-1" class="menu menu-box-right menu-box-detached menu-sidebar" data-menu-width="310" style="display: block; width: 310px;">
            <div class="sidebar-content">
                <div class="bg-theme mx-3 rounded-m shadow-m my-3">
                    <div class="d-flex px-2 pb-2 pt-2">
                        <div class="align-self-center">
                            <a href="#" class="icon-xxl ">
                                <i class="fa fa-solid fa-user-tie" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ps-2 align-self-center">
                            <h5 class="ps-1 mb-1 pt-1 line-height-xs font-17"><?php echo $_SESSION[
           "username"
       ]; ?></h5>                   
                        </div>              
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-style">
                    <div class="content my-0">
                        <h5 class="font-700 text-uppercase opacity-40 font-12 pt-2 mb-0">Action</h5>
                        <div class="list-group list-custom-small list-icon-0">
                            <a href="changepassword.php">
                                <i class="fa font-12 fa-cog gradient-red rounded-sm color-white"></i>
                                <span>Change password</span>
                            </a>                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>  
        </div>

        <!-- All Menus, Action Sheets, Modals, Notifications, Toasts, Snackbars get Placed outside the <div class="page-content"> -->
        <div id="menu-settings" class="menu menu-box-bottom menu-box-detached">
            <div class="menu-title mt-0 pt-0">
                <h1>Settings</h1>
                <p class="color-highlight">Flexible and Easy to Use</p>
                <a href="#" class="close-menu">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
            <div class="divider divider-margins mb-n2"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="list-group list-custom-small">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle-theme data-trigger-switch="switch-dark-mode" class="pb-2 ms-n1">
                        <i class="fa font-12 fa-moon rounded-s bg-highlight color-white me-3"></i>
                        <span>Dark Mode</span>
                        <div class="custom-control scale-switch ios-switch">
                            <input data-toggle-theme type="checkbox" class="ios-input" id="switch-dark-mode">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="switch-dark-mode"></label>
                        </div>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group list-custom-large">
                    <a data-menu="menu-highlights" href="#">
                        <i class="fa font-14 fa-tint bg-green-dark rounded-s"></i>
                        <span>Page Highlight</span>
                        <strong>16 Colors Highlights Included</strong>
                        <span class="badge bg-highlight color-white">HOT</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a data-menu="menu-backgrounds" href="#" class="border-0">
                        <i class="fa font-14 fa-cog bg-blue-dark rounded-s"></i>
                        <span>Background Color</span>
                        <strong>10 Page Gradients Included</strong>
                        <span class="badge bg-highlight color-white">NEW</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Menu Settings Highlights-->
        <div id="menu-highlights" class="menu menu-box-bottom menu-box-detached">
            <div class="menu-title">
                <h1>Highlights</h1>
                <p class="color-highlight">Any Element can have a Highlight Color</p>
                <a href="#" class="close-menu">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
            <div class="divider divider-margins mb-n2"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="highlight-changer">
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="blue">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-blue-dark"></i><span class="color-blue-light">Default</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="red">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-red-dark"></i><span class="color-red-light">Red</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="orange">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-orange-dark"></i><span class="color-orange-light">Orange</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="pink2">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-pink2-dark"></i><span class="color-pink-dark">Pink</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="magenta">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-magenta-dark"></i><span class="color-magenta-light">Purple</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="aqua">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-aqua-dark"></i><span class="color-aqua-light">Aqua</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="teal">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-teal-dark"></i><span class="color-teal-light">Teal</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="mint">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-mint-dark"></i><span class="color-mint-light">Mint</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="green">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-green-light"></i><span class="color-green-light">Green</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="grass">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-green-dark"></i><span class="color-green-dark">Grass</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="sunny">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-yellow-light"></i><span class="color-yellow-light">Sunny</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="yellow">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-yellow-dark"></i><span class="color-yellow-light">Goldish</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="brown">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-brown-dark"></i><span class="color-brown-light">Wood</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="night">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-dark-dark"></i><span class="color-dark-light">Night</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-highlight="dark">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle color-dark-light"></i><span class="color-dark-light">Dark</span></a>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" data-menu="menu-settings" class="mb-3 btn btn-full btn-m rounded-sm bg-highlight shadow-xl text-uppercase font-900 mt-4">Back to Settings</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Menu Settings Backgrounds-->
        <div id="menu-backgrounds" class="menu menu-box-bottom menu-box-detached">
            <div class="menu-title">
                <h1>Backgrounds</h1>
                <p class="color-highlight">Change Page Color Behind Content Boxes</p>
                <a href="#" class="close-menu">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
            <div class="divider divider-margins mb-n2"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="background-changer">
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="default">
                        <i class="bg-theme"></i><span class="color-dark-dark">Default</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="plum">
                        <i class="body-plum"></i><span class="color-plum-dark">Plum</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="magenta">
                        <i class="body-magenta"></i><span class="color-dark-dark">Magenta</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="dark">
                        <i class="body-dark"></i><span class="color-dark-dark">Dark</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="violet">
                        <i class="body-violet"></i><span class="color-violet-dark">Violet</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="red">
                        <i class="body-red"></i><span class="color-red-dark">Red</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="green">
                        <i class="body-green"></i><span class="color-green-dark">Green</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="sky">
                        <i class="body-sky"></i><span class="color-sky-dark">Sky</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="orange">
                        <i class="body-orange"></i><span class="color-orange-dark">Orange</span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-change-background="yellow">
                        <i class="body-yellow"></i><span class="color-yellow-dark">Yellow</span></a>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" data-menu="menu-settings" class="mb-3 btn btn-full btn-m rounded-sm bg-highlight shadow-xl text-uppercase font-900 mt-4">Back to Settings</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"> </script>
</body>

this is my dashboard page, when i click on "<a href="#" class="icon rounded-xs me-1 icon-xs bg-fade-red-light" onclick="postToHome(" link it takes me another page but when i come once again to this page
chart not showing and the this link not working giving following error
dashboard.php:1 Uncaught 
ReferenceError: postToHome is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (dashboard.php:1:1)

but when i refresh the page its start working
i observed when i camo back to dashboard page this <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/charts/charts.js"></script> is not showing in source , on refresh its showing once again

Have you checked the script is being rendered on the page (ie view source and see if the script with postToHome is there)  - it could be within a php if that isn't being satisfied on your second visit

yes, postToHome showing in source on second visit

What is this if statement for: if (!header("Location: index.php"))? header() doesn't return anything.

So that condition will always succeed, and you'll always go to die("Unauthorized access");

i removed that complete if block but still have the same issue

i use the anchor tag  to return the dashboard, when i use the form & submit button its work perfectly, what the problem ?
